# _mm_xor_pd fails with product = 0

Tags: c++, opencl

I am embarking on learning to transition some code I have working in integer math to make use of faster GPU floating point operation. I can not see why I can not get _mm_xor_pd() working. 
For test purposes only I have populated the same value into both vectors as thus:

```
__m128d shift04 = _mm_set1_pd(16);

__m128d v1 = _mm_set1_pd(0x33F4A032);

__m128d k0 = _mm_set1_pd(0x6A6BA9EF);

__m128d j = _mm_add_pd(_mm_mul_pd(v1,shift04),k0); //  j = (v1 << 4) + k0

__m128d k = _mm_add_pd(v1,sum);                    //  k = v1 + sum

__m128d l = _mm_xor_pd(j,k);                       //  l = j ^ k
```

I appreciate the code above is atrocious but it is only for basic testing so please be patient with me. The value of `l[0]` and `l[1]` is `0`?

`j[0]` correctly equals `0xa9b5ad0f`

`k[0]` correctly equals `0xd22c19eb`

`l[0]` should equal `0x7b99b4e4` but the above code produces `0x0000000`.

I am currently assuming it is because you can not normally XOR floating points, but the function clearly suggests that what it does. Am I wrong?

Ubuntu 19.1, G++ version 9.2.1, Radeon VII and Intel I7 2600k.

Comment: Note these are SIMD CPU instructions and are nothing to do with the GPU, you need to use OpenCL, Cuda or Vulcan to do GPU processing

Answer (score 2):

You can XOR floating point numbers with `_mm_xor_pd`, but that really XORs *floating point numbers*, it does not convert the floats to integers and XOR those. Floats are more complicated than integers, for example multiplying by 16 doesn't shift the bits, it increases the exponent by 4 and leaves the other bits in place (except for denormal numbers or when the exponent overflows or some other edge cases).

The result here is probably not zero (I can't test it because `sum` is not defined) but tiny, such that converting it to an integer results in zero.

> transition some code I have working in integer math to make use of faster GPU floating point operation

There is integer SIMD too, fortunately, so you can just use that and not fight the floats.

For example:

```
__m128i v1 = _mm_set1_epi32(0x33F4A032);
__m128i k0 = _mm_set1_epi32(0x6A6BA9EF);
__m128i j = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_slli_epi32(v1, 4), k0); //  j = (v1 << 4) + k0
__m128i k = _mm_add_epi32(v1, sum);                   //  k = v1 + sum
__m128i l = _mm_xor_si128(j, k);                      //  l = j ^ k
```

Keep in mind though that the main point of SIMD is the vectorization, it is not very useful to use it with always the same value in every "lane", that's just wasting 3/4th of the potential.

Comment: Yes - I think for now I will concentrate on refining integer math efficiency as much as I can. I have no clear understanding of how I can convert the XOR maths to FP math and be computationally more efficient. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are xoring the bits of the doubles not the integer values you stored in the doubles. If you print out the bits you will see you are getting the correct value (which is not `0` but a very small number: `7e-290`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main()
{
    __m128d sum = _mm_set1_pd(0x9E3779B9);
    __m128d shift04 = _mm_set1_pd(16);
    __m128d v1 = _mm_set1_pd(0x33F4A032);
    __m128d k0 = _mm_set1_pd(0x6A6BA9EF);
    __m128d j = _mm_add_pd(_mm_mul_pd(v1,shift04),k0); //  j = (v1 << 4) + k0
    __m128d k = _mm_add_pd(v1,sum);                    //  k = v1 + sum
    __m128d l = _mm_xor_pd(j,k);
    std::cout << l[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&j[0]) << "^" << *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&k[0]) << " = " << *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&l[0]) << "\n";  
}
```

Note don't use the above code for anything important, accessing elements of `__m128d` is undefined behaviour as is `reinterpret_cast`ing them to an `int64_t`.

The program outputs:

```
7.38559e-290
420d4dad68780000^41ea45833d600000 = 3e7082e55180000
```

`0x420d4dad68780000 ^ 0x41ea45833d600000` is `0x3e7082e55180000`

Comment: And this is why I asked here - newbie misunderstanding resolved thank you!!!!